# “The application is in break mode" C# when using throw to bubble out the exception

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

When I am throwing exception my function to bubble it out and catch it in the task exception, rather then continuation it breaks the code- below is my code

```
public override void Run()
{
    SendRenewalsEmail("ddd@xxx.com", " Email Body from test More", "Test Email from Service another Test");
}

private async void SendRenewalsEmail(string userEmail, string emailBody, string emailSubject)
{
    string replyFromEmailAddress = "renewals@xxx.net";
    string cc = "";
    string bcc = "ccc@xxxx.com";
    SMTPMailHelperAsync sMTPMailHelperAsync = new SMTPMailHelperAsync();
    var x= await sMTPMailHelperAsync.SendEmailAsync(userEmail, cc, bcc, emailSubject, SMTPMailHelperAsync.ProcessTemplate(emailBody, "Renewals.html", emailSubject), replyFromEmailAddress);

    if (x.MailSent)
    {
        throw new Exception("after mail Test more service");
    }
}
```

and the Task where it is being captured

```
var task=  Task<PluginInstance>.Run<PluginInstance>(() => {
    thisPlugin.LastRunStart = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    try
    {
        thisPlugin.Plugin.Run();
        thisPlugin.LastRunStatus = Enums.RunStatus.Success;
        thisPlugin.LastRunMessage = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        thisPlugin.LastRunStatus = Enums.RunStatus.Failed;
        thisPlugin.LastRunMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    thisPlugin.LastRunEnd = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    return thisPlugin;
});

ListOfTask.Add(task);
```

Now I am trying to capture the exception in the Task exception but is not. getting below exception
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use `async void`.  This is a special case, reserved only for event handlers.  Your `async` method must return a `Task`:

```
private async Task SendRenewalsEmail(…)
```

Then, your `Plugin.Run` method is broken.  It should be `async` as well.

Once you start with `async - await`, you do it to the top.